# Save Conditional sum result in variable MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, sum

I am stuck in a query I want to store sum result in a variable where status = 3, what happening right now is it store the value of last row and show it with all rows

Here is the query

```
    SELECT 
request_made_on,driver_id,
@sum_result = SUM(status = 3) AS complete_count,@sum_result,
SUM(status = 6) AS missed_count,
(status = 4) AS canceled_count,
sum(actual_fare),sum(discount)
 from tb_engagements
 group by date(request_made_on),driver_id;
```

[and here is the screenshot,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEqvP.png)
[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5xuw.png)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  How do you expect to store multiple values in one variable?

Comment: Please check the screenshot, I want to store sum result of each row against it

Comment: Use `:=`, not `=` for assignment in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want the *sum* of all the values:

```
select request_made_on, driver_id,
       (@sum_result := @sum_result + SUM(status = 3)) AS complete_count,
       sum(status = 6) AS missed_count,
       sum(status = 4) AS canceled_count,
       sum(actual_fare),
       sum(discount)
from tb_engagements c cross join
     (select @sum_result := 0) params
group by date(accept_time), driver_id;
```

Notes:

- You don't need to return the value of the variable as well as the expression.  The expression adds a column to the result set with the value.
- You don't need `if()` to count values.  MySQL has a nice short-hand, treating boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context.

Comment: sum of each complete_count against it 

Suppose if complete count is 0 in a row then variable value should be 0 and so on

Comment: the query you shared did not work. it give wrong calculation of status 3

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: isn't it necessary to write (@sum_result := COALESCE(@sum_result,0) + SUM(...  ?

Comment: @etsa . . . That depends on how the variable is initialized.  I added initialization code to the answer.

Comment: I don't think there is any need for the cross join, nor for the incrementation of @sum_result.  Simply set it.